# Convert currency within Paypal form and send to Paypal as GBP

Tags: php, paypal

Wonder if anyone can help. I'm putting a Paypal payment form on a website where the user enters a pre-agreed amount and the payment is sent.

The problem is, I wondered if there was a way that the user would enter the amount in Chinese Yuan Renminbi (currency not supported by Paypal so can't be sent to PP for conversion) and the conversion would be shown in GBP below that (in a text field or line below) and it is the GBP amount that is sent to Paypal?

I have looked at including a php currency converter on the page that would give the user the GBP amount they need to enter in the payment form but that is clunky and a step I'd like to avoid if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Paypal can't accept any currency it doesn't deal in. Remember, they would still be paying you in Yuan. They would have to have their money in GBP (or some other accepted form) before sending it to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I know it doesn't accept it so what I want to do is for the user to type in the amount in Yuan in the form and the converted amount in GBP is outputted below in a text field which is the amount that is sent to Paypal - is this possible using php or javascript?

Comment: As long as they will pay you in GBP, then yes, it is possible. There are some APIs out there that can feed you the current conversion rates.